# Wordpress template names not appearing

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have been searching for answers to this problem for over 2 hours now and need help.
I have been working on a site for a client and want to make it into a wordpress them so that they can edit content without my help.

A few of the pages will need to have a template. So far I have 5 named custom templates within my theme.

- Home Page
- Support
- Consultation
- FAQ
- Terminology

The pages are nested in different folders to create clean urls like so:

zulu_theme(main_dir)

zulu_theme/homepage.php (template name: homepage)

zulu_theme/consultation/index.php (template name: consultation)

zulu_theme/support/index.php (template name: support)

zulu_theme/support/faq/index.php (template name: faq, *template name not showing*)

zulu_theme/support/terminology/index.php (template name: terminology, *template name not showing*)

I have checked the problem files to see to see if I specified the name correctly. Both of them have /* Template Name: -template name */ correctly formatted on the second line of the document like the others.

I have tried changing the theme back to default and resetting it, however that doesnt work either.

I moved the zulu_theme/support/faq/index.php file to the theme folder to the zulu_folder/ and the faq name showed up, so I think that it is a permissions issue. However, when I check the folder and file permissions everything looks okay.

Has anybody else run into this issue, and found a solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use templates if they're inside sub-folders. Try to move the files to the parent folder and see if it works.

Comment: I does work, but I also have my consultation and support page inside sub folders within the theme and they work fine. If possible I would like to maintain the structure to allow the urls to be structured in a certain way.

Comment: Your Wordpress version is updated? This should work in Wordpress 3.4 and above.

Comment: I'm running version 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using themes within 1 level of subfolders and they work. I haven't tried going further levels down but i think you should try keeping it simple. Also replace the file names with relavant names. If i was in your position i would try to use this structure.

```
zulu_theme/templates/homepage.php
zulu_theme/templates/faq.php
zulu_theme/templates/terminology.php
...
```

Comment: Yeah I just checked the documentation. Apparently, you can only nest themes within level 1 subfolders. Lame.